# ARRAY- Accept user input and output the corresponding choice from array

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, array

I'm working on a script that has an array of around 10 elements.
All I have to do is that the script will accept user input of minimum 0 elements and maximum 10 elements (of the array) and it will execute whatever the corresponding array element says.

---

**Example**

Array -

```
array0=( [1]=echo "Foo" [2]=export CCACHE=true [3]=export FOO_FLAG=true [4]=unset BAR_FLAG )
```

Then the script will read inputs like -

```
read -a array0
```

And then something like -

```
for i in ${array0[@]}
do
   access each element as $i. . .
done
```

The output should look something like -

```
Type the elements - 1 4 2

Foo
*unset BAR_FLAG
*export CCACHE=true*
```

But i'm not able to do it unfortunately. There must be some mistake in the for/do loop.

**If anybody can help...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

array0=('echo Foo' 'export CCACHE=true' 'export FOO_FLAG=true' 'unset BAR_FLAG')

echo -n "Enter the elements: "

read -e line

for index in $line;do
        ${array0[index]}
done
```

Usage: `script.sh`

First index of an array is `0`.

Comment: I can use `read` here too right?

Comment: Modified the script to wait for user input.